# Angularjs and ecommerce: compatible?

Tags: angularjs

As [Angular 1.3 has dropped support for ie8](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) (and below):

> does it mean you would need to build and maintain two versions of an ecommerce website?

Or do you just hope that **all** your potential buyers have updated their browser?

Comment: Chances are 20%, according to these statistics : https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0&qptimeframe=Y

Comment: @Claies Win7 users aren't all necessarily using IE9+, since [IE8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) is the default/original IE browser to come with Win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on who your customers are, where they're from etc.

For example, according to these statistics:

http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-eu-monthly-201401-201501

IE8 usage in Europe is at 2%. If you're catering to techies, then that's probably going to be even lower.

Just for fun, the same site claims that IE8 usage in Asia is at 4.5% and 5% in North America. Step it up North Americans!

The percentage will vary according to which statistic you choose to believe in. Ultimately you have to judge if the added cost of maintaining IE8-compatible code will be worth it. Personally I think the world is ready to ditch IE8.

Edit: Just took a look at what they base their data on. StatCounter claim their statistics are gathered from 3 million global sites. Netmarketshare say their statistics come from 40000 sites.

Comment: We'll lose ie8 and get angular 2.0: not so bad :)